# How to correct url of GitHub portfolio

Tags: github, github-pages, github-actions, github-for-windows

Need a help in GitHub
I hosted my portfolio on GitHub but there is an issue.

Hosted link is https://gfx-usman.github.io/gfxusman.github.io/

But I need to convert in this link:
https://gfxusman.github.io/

what's the problem? Is it any repository creation issue. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)
 says:

> To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<username>.github.io`

In your case the repo name should be `gfx-usman.github.io` instead of `gfxusman.github.io`

Answer (score 0):

Don't add .github.io in your repo name.
Repo name - gfxusman
And then publish it then you will get
Link - https://gfxusman.github.io/